# Need assistance on Print function

Tags: python-3.x, printf

Hey so I was wondering if there was a way to write say a calculated number before the text in a print output. The only way I know how is to put the value from the program after the text like this:

```
a=3+4
print("Your number is", a)
```

I'm curious if there's a way to put the value first and then the text in the print

Comment: What happened when you tried `print(a, " was your number")`?

Comment: Never tried that haha I tried print(,a " was your number") but not that. Thank you so much I knew it would be something simple like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beginning and end are special cases, you can just use

```
print(a, "is your number.")
```

or

```
print("Your number is ", a)
```

If you need a period at the end of the sentence. You could use this

```
print("Your number is ", a, ".")
```

But that way it's not so clear to see how the parts fit together. Imagine if there were 10 or more parts! In general cases it's preferred to use the `format` method, eg

```
print("Your number is {}.".format(a))
```

or even

```
print("Your number is {a}.".format(a=a))
```

`format` also lets you left/right/center justify, add leading zeros, specify precision and many other hand things

Answer (score 1):

Just do `print(a, "is your number")`